# How to split an SVG file with dozens of g elements into dozens of SVG files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, batch-processing, automation

I have an SVG file that has, say, 10 g elements that do not start at (0,0). For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="528px"
     height="240px" viewBox="0 0 528 240" enable-background="new 0 0 528 240" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="CONTAINER">
    <g id="collapse-top">
        <path id="collapse_x5F_top" fill="#1D1D1B" d="M498,206v-3c0-2.2-1.8-4-4-4h-3c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4v3c0,2.156,1.781,4,4,4
            c0,0,2,0,3,0C496.172,210,498,208.156,498,206z M496,207c0,0.55-0.45,1-1,1h-5c-0.55,0-1-0.45-1-1v-5c0-0.55,0.45-1,1-1h5
            c0.55,0,1,0.45,1,1V207z M495,206h-5l2.5-3.333L495,206z"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

How can I split it into 10 different SVG files, one per g element, that each start at (0,0)?

I prefer an automated, command-line based approach to do this, but I can use Adobe Illustrator as well.

Comment: Related question: [Can I make each group in this SVG file its own SVG file?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17585/can-i-make-each-group-in-this-svg-file-its-own-svg-file)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple ways I can think of to do this:

### Option 1: Modify the `d` attribute on the Object

**Difficulty rating: ★★★★☆**

Conceptually, this is pretty simple. The nitty gritty details are the issue. in the `<path>` object within the `<g>`, you have the `d` attribute. This is the main thing you need to modify. What you'll need to do is [decode that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/d) and translate it to the updated coordinates.

---

### Option 2: Add a transform Attribute to the Object

**Difficulty rating: ★★☆☆☆**

If you have a good grasp with JavaScript, this is pretty easy. You can get the bounding box of the graphic using **[getBBox()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox)**. You can then use that rect to add a transform attribute to the object, like so:

```js
transform = "translate(-100 -100)"
```

This would move the object 100 units to the left and 100 units up. Using the example you provided, I added the following script:

```js
<script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
  var path = document.getElementById("collapse_x5F_top");
  var x = path.getBBox().x;
  var y = path.getBBox().y;

  path.setAttribute("transform", "translate(-" + x + " -" + y + ")");
]]> </script>
```

This moves the graphic to the top right corner of the screen.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9N4Lg/)** *(The red icon is the original, the black is the transformed object)*

**Please note that while this code works for *this* example, it is not robust code that will work for every test case (for instance, if values of x and y are not initially positive)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way to do this with Adobe Illustrator

1. Use the "release to layers" option on the layers panel to move each element into its own layer
2. Use the [smart layer export script](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/2955#.V-uPiS997XE) to export each layer into a new .svg file. If you use the option to "trim edges", they should all be at 0,0.